# Why does mapreduce split a compressed file into input splits?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

So from my understanding, when hdfs stores a bzip2 compressed 1GB file with a block size of 64 MB, the file will be stored as 16 different blocks. If I want to run a map-reduce job on this compressed file, map reduce tries to split the file again. Why doesn't mapreduce automatically use the 16 blocks in hdfs instead of splitting the file again?

Comment: What do you mean "split again"? Are you saying that MapReduce chooses different splits than what you expect?

Comment: For example, you have your own input format that requires the file to be split by sequence `abc123`. Obviously you have to go through the file and re-break it into splits.

Comment: Hi @climbage dividing a file into blocks to store in hdfs and splitting a file for map reduce jobs are two independent processes. My question: If the files are stored as blocks on hdfs, how and why does a map reduce job split the files again? I hope this question is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see where your confusion is coming from.  I'll attempt to clear it up.

HDFS slices your file up into blocks.  These are physical partitions of the file.

MapReduce creates **logical** splits on top of these blocks.  These splits are defined based on a number of parameters, with block boundaries and locations being a huge factor. You can set your minimum split size to 128MB, in which case each split will likely be exactly two 64MB blocks.

All of this is unrelated to your bzip2 compression.  If you had used gzip compression, each split would be an entire file because gzip is not a splittable compression.